# python version 3.6.3 Functions and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, python-3.6

I am trying to run the following:

```
def count_small(numbers):
total = 0
for n in numbers:
    if n < 10:
        total = total + 1
    return total

lotto = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
small = count_small(lotto)
print(small)
```

Here I have defined a function 'count_small(numbers)'
it starts with a total of 0,
then checks each item in the list, to check that it is less than 10, if the item is less then 10, then 1 will be added to the total. I am running the function on the list 'lotto', as you can see 'lotto' has two numbers less than 10 '4' and '8' hence it should return 2, however, when I run the code it returns 1 instead.

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: Fun fact: You can achieve the same thing just by doing `small = sum(n < 10 for n in lotto)`

Comment: You cannot possibly have run **this** code, the code that you list. That may be obscuring the real error.

Comment: I'm flagging this question for closure. The asker was able to find their issue which is good, but the error was a small typographical mistake (indentation of `return`) which was resolved in a way to help future readers, so the question should now be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `return` statement is inside the for-loop, so that the function is left after the first number.

```
def count_small(numbers):
    total = 0
    for n in numbers:
        if n < 10:
            total += 1
    return total
```

When you use a generator expression, you can write this in one line:

```
def count_small(numbers):
    return sum(n<10 for n in numbers)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot, and the simplification is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is incorrect. Place the return statement outside of your for loop.

Comment: Thank you! A small mistake, it runs now :)